# tkinter: AttributeError: 'Button' object has no attribute 'get' when trying to access file from filedialog.askopenfilename

Tags: python, tkinter

So I have something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
import pandas as pd

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('350x240')

def open_file():
    temp_file = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Open file", filetypes=[("Excel files", "*.csv")])
    temp_file = open(temp_file, "r")
    Proj_df = pd.read_csv(temp_file)

open_button = ttk.Button(text='Select File...', command=open_file)
open_button.grid(column=1, row=1)

def get_info():
    x = open_button.get()
    print (x)

button1 = ttk.Button(text='Get Information', command=get_info)

button1.grid(column=0, row=2)
```

What I'm trying to do is to store the DataFrame created in `open_file()` to use it in `get_info()`. I'm getting:

> AttributeError: 'Button' object has no attribute 'get'

How could I access the DataFrame created in `open_button`?

Comment: make it `global`, there is really no way to retrieve values from functions that are called by a `Button` from that `Button` (I mean it is not impossible to create a button that would be able to do this, but it is much easier to just use `global` (or OOP))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might help you along the way.  You can set a tk.StringVar then use to retrieve, store, and access items that are input through various tk/ttk widgets.  Also I suppose you might want to store your inbound file?  I ran this attempt simply reading in the csv, not using pandas.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import filedialog, ttk
#import pandas as pd

window = tk.Tk()
window.geometry('350x240')
tkvar1 = tk.StringVar(window)

def open_file():
    temp_file = filedialog.askopenfilename(title="Open file", filetypes=[("Excel files", "*.csv")])
    temp_file = open(temp_file, "r")
    tkvar1.set(temp_file.read())
    #Proj_df = pd.read_csv(temp_file)

open_button = ttk.Button(text='Select File...', command=open_file)
open_button.grid(column=1, row=1)

def get_info():
    x = tkvar1.get()
    print (x)

button1 = ttk.Button(text='Get Information', command=get_info)

button1.grid(column=0, row=2)
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried that but I'm not being able to create the DataFrame later on, it returns `pandas.errors.EmptyDataError: No columns to parse from file` , I added the steps as per suggestion and in the `get_info()` part I tried creating a dataframe with x:
`df = pd.read_csv(x)`

Comment: That sounds like an issue with your inbound data?  read_csv can take a file or buffer https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html